# Advanced throttling works one server but not on other servers

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have 4 WSO2AM servers (not clustered) all pointing to same DB instance. I have enabled advanced throttling, and have created subscription tier policy, but it does not seem to kick in on all instances.

All servers have gateway/key manager/traffic manager running locally (not clustered). Since they point to the same db instance, all traffic managers should be able to retrieve the policy and apply it to every call.

I created the subscription for the application on 1 server using REST api. When I go to other 3 servers, and when I fetch the subscription list for this application, I see it having the correct tier.

The server on which the subscription was created does throttle correctly.

Server 1: Created subscription for the application using the new tier
Server 1/2/3/4: when calling /api/am/store/v0.14/subscriptions?applicationId=5DBAC189B8820398E05400144FF96272, do retrieve the correct tier level
Server 1: calling the end point resource is throttled.
Server 2/3/4: calling the end point resource is not throttled.

I do not want to or need to cluster the 4 servers, I have a load balancer in front of them to channel the traffic in a balanced fashion.

I would expect all 4 WSO servers to throttle that application's access to the downstream services.

Any pointers on why other 3 servers do not throttle/apply policy? May be a way to have the other servers reload data from the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runtime artifact of the throttling policy is deployed in the file system. (in repository/deployment/server/executionplans/) Currently, it's deployed on the created node only. That's why you see rate limiting in that node only. So, to fix this, you need to share these within all 4 nodes. You must be already doing the same for Synapse files. Do the same for the execution plans as well.

Another thing to note is, since each gateway talks to their local TM, the throttling counts will local (not shared) too. If that's a problem, I suggest you have an external TM and make all GWs publish to that TM node.

Comment: This did the job! Thank you so much. Are there other files that I need to double check across all the instances?

Comment: Those 2 types should be enough.